# Is C/C++ pointer keeps absolute memory address, or relative to application, or relative to module?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

For example, if I declare a function in the main application, and a pass a pointer to it, from a dynamically loaded library (via `dlopen` under Linux or `LoadLibrary` under Windows) using a gotten symbol argument (via `dlsym` or `GetProcAddress` respectively) and try to call that function, would it work properly?

Same if pass pointer from one dynamically loaded library to another? I think it should work if pointer at least relative to application but not relative to module/library.

Another example. I declare a function in one application and pass pointer to it to another fully-independent application (both C and C++) somehow (parameter string or file i/o - idk how, just an idea) and try to call this function, would it work too? I could expect it to work if the pointers are absolute. Maybe it just won't work because system won't like such cross-call at all because of safety?

Comment: does it matter in any way to your program?

Comment: Well, sharing between processes has no matter for my program, just generalizing question. Sharing between dynamically and statically loaded libraries in my program is what I need to, because plugin might call main app's functions indirectly, through address.

Comment: Maybe it could be another question... I have a main app, main library (linked) and a plugins to be load dynamically. Main application registers an array of objects, containing addresses of functions in some fields (type declared in library header, defined in library source). Plugin include library header but register nothing, just take that objects and run functions at addresses as declared in library header. I have tested, it works, I hope it would result no problems if address space is the same for whole process at all platforms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you must understand that in C and C++ the value of a pointer is not required to be related to the addresses actually used, as long as pointer arithmetic works with it, the null pointer has an R value of 0 and the implementation manages to bijectively map between machine pointers and language abstract pointers.

On modern systems processes see a virtual address space and each process has its own address space. Libraries may be loaded to any address, thus passing a pointer between processes is utter nonsense – at least on paged memory architectures. However within a process machine level pointers are passed between loaded libraries with no problem; after all they share the same address space. On the language level they may not be the same (though usually the are), if multiple languages get into contact. But compilation units created using the same compiler will use the same pointer semantics. Also most language implementations that target the native machine agree on the pointer semantics for the simple reason, that having to convert between pointer formats would create a huge performance hit.

Comment: But... what if main application library and shared library build using different compiler - both C++, but different manufactures, or versions? Would cross-calling one library function from another library works fine?

Comment: @Nick: Usually it will, because operating systems and architectures define a so called "ABI", i.e. the binary interfaces between processes and the OS. Those ABI define how functions are called on the machine level, how calls to the OS are made and so on. And because programmers are lazy, that includes the programmers of compilers, and because it makes the most sense, all compilers targeting a specific plattform will agree on the ABI. But keep in mind that this is a plattform thing, not a language thing.

Answer (score 7):

It's **absolute**.

The fact that it's a *virtual* address has nothing to do with this -- it's an **absolute** virtual address. It makes *no difference* to your program whether it's using virtual memory or physical memory... you shouldn't concern yourself with this unless you're passing pointers *between processes* (which I seriously doubt you are), or unless you're writing low-level kernel code or mapping/unmapping pages manually (which I also doubt you are).

Answer (score 5):

Things work differently on different operating systems. On older / embedded operating systems all processes share the same space - one process can easily mess things for another.

On most general-purpose (i.e. not embedded) modern operating systems each process has a separate address space. All addresses are relative to this space. It doesn't matter how things are compiled / linked together, if they're in the same **process**, they share the address space.

It follows that two distinct processes have no implicit ways of accessing each-others space.

Answer (score 4):

Is is due to [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit). It is hardware unit in most processors for protecting applications from each other. Its main purpose is to protect kernel/OS from application. Each application or process has its own memory and can not access memory of other process, but has to go trough kernel/OS in some way.

Comment: @avakar Win95 loaded DLLs in memory that was shared between all processes - one rogue or buggy process could ruin the entire system.

Comment: @snemarch, all Windows versions do that, but the pages are not writable. Hell, I hope Linux does it too -- it would be wasteful to keep multiple copies of the same data.

Comment: @avakar there's quite a difference between mapping the same physical pages into multiple processes, and the Win9x style "DLLs shared between processes". Also, there's less sharing of physical pages after ASLR was introduced.

Comment: to elaborate, *one* process on 9x can nuke *all* loaded DLLs, since they're cross-process shared. On NT, DLLs get mapped separately into each process, and if you VirtualProtect and overwrite a loaded DLL, you get CopyOnWrite and only your own process' copy of the DLL gets modified.

Comment: @snemarch, so what is the difference between "mapping the same physical pages into multiple processes" and "Win9x style DLLs shared between processes"? I understand the former, I have no idea what you mean by the latter. As for ASLR, system DLLs are still shared, the randomization is performed only once for each of them and the resulting sections are kept open and reused.

Comment: @avakar NT does the mapping selectively per process. For 9x, virtual 2-4GB are shared between all processes. 2-3GB is used for DLLs and memory mapped files, 3-4GB is used for "kernel stuff"... and 9x doesn't really have copy on write. So you have a global view of ALL DLLs and MMFs available to all processes. NT creates per-process PTEs that point to the (shared) physical pages.

Comment: (the memory addresses are off top of my head, and it's been several years since I've had to deal with win9x - consult Matt Pietrek material if you need exact ranges :-) )